# Socket connection reset before I could read the data

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm having a problem receiving data from a client using .net sockets. The client is communicating with TCP and sending one or two packets before closing the connection immediatly. The reception go like this :

```
Socket newConnection = listener.EndAccept(ar);
newConnection.BeginReceive(myBuffer,0, length, SocketFlags.None, Callback,null);
```

and the execution won't go further. The beginReceive will immediatly throw a SocketException saying the connection was reset. I can't manage to get the received data.

Here is what I see for this connection on wireshark :

```
SYN // SYN, AKC // AKC
PSH, ACK for 156 bytes
PSH, ACK for 176 bytes
RST, ACK
```

And that's it. Is there any means to get this received data even though the connection is closed by the client?

Comment: Is there any way you can have your client wait for an "acknowledged" packet from your receiving program before closing?

Comment: I can't really. The client is used on other servers and it works, so I should be able to do the same. I have no access to the source code of these other servers to see how the do it.

Comment: Not much you can do if you haven't read the data before a RST comes in (this indicates the sender is doing an abortive close).  Why is the sender sending a RST instead of a FIN (i.e. graceful close, [Socket.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown.aspx))?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no valid reason for closing with a RST. I essentially wanted to find a way to make my server work without changing the client behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, RST indicates to the kernel that something went wrong and to immediately tear down the connection (hence why RST doesn't ACK; there's no connection any more).  If you are gracefully shutting down on the sender side (the client, in this case) and it, in turn, has data in its receive buffer, it might explain why a RST is being unexpectedly sent.  A RST in this case is signaling that data was lost because the sender closed the socket without reading all of its data.  Otherwise, we should expect a FIN/ACK exchange for a graceful shutdown.

Comment: So essentially, there is nothing I can do to get this data, since at the socket level, the connection was forced to close? I'll have to check at the client implementation to see why he is closing the connection that way then.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.  Generally speaking, the only time you could "normally" see a RST is when the client knows there is no more data to read from either side and closes the connection without doing a shutdown.  This could happen for an application protocol like HTTP where the client knows how much data there is to read in the response via the Content-Length header.  So instead of waiting for an ACK to a FIN, it could just send a RST to save time.  However, the client in this case knows the server received all data sent because it got the one and only response from the server.

Comment: Could you post more specific details about the client? What was the intended server for which the client was designed? It could be, quite probably, that the client is designed to actively abort any connection to any server that doesn't meet its expectations (e.g., if you're trying to trick the client into connecting to a server other than the ones the authors approved, the client is aborting the connection). I would suggest contacting the author of the client and requesting more information.

Comment: The client implementation is in-house and after the answers I got, we looked more closely to it and found a problem where the client wouldn't receive response from a request. My tests were on the loopback address so the RST was received almost immediately, preventing my server to read anything. On a real network, servers could get in a race with the RST and sometime get the data and respond, sometimes not. Since the major problem was that after 5 request without response, the client would drop the connection, the race would not happen often enough to get noticed for what it was.

Comment: Check if you are not overwriting the variables and trying to listen/receive from another connection more than once with the same addresses

Answer (score -1):

First of all with this type of communication it might be a good idea to switch to UDP instead of TCP - that way you will be able to get the packets regardless of the state of the sender.
Assuming TCP is the only option - I would suggest using synchronous calls:

```
Socket newConnection = listener.AcceptSocket();
newConnection.Receive(myBuffer, 0, length, SocketFlags.None);
```

Comment: If he has to change the client to use UDP, he might as well change it not the send the RST.

Comment: And using synchronous call doesn't change anything. The socket will still get reset by the time the AcceptSocket call finishes and Receive will still throw